# Automapper Mapper.DynamicMap(....)

Tags: automapper, automapper-4

`Mapper.DynamicMap(object, source, destination)` is deprecated in the latest version of Automapper.

What is the alternative of this method when the source and destination values are not known until runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. It was all put into one method:

```
Mapper.Map(object, source, destination)
```